# Check if data block record is in edit or add state

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracleforms

I am working on a data block in oracle forms builders which lists editable records. I recently added a functionality which lets me add a new item to the datablock for adding a new record. Below is an illustration:

[image]

I loop through data items in the datablock to check the data. My question is, how do I know if the item is newly added, or an edited record, without having to check the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `:SYSTEM.RECORD_STATUS` system variable.

- `CHANGED`: Indicates that a queried record's validation status is Changed.
- `INSERT`: Indicates that the record's validation status is Changed and that the record does not exist in the database.
- `NEW`: Indicates that the record's validation status is New.
- `QUERY`: Indicates that the record's validation status is Valid and that it was retrieved from the database.

In your loop, you'd check e.g.

```
if :system.record_status = 'INSERT' then 
   ...
end if;
```

For more info, open Forms Online Help system and search for it.